# Margin between elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to make the inputs have a margin between them. I though `form-group` was supposed to handle this but the margin is not working.

Why is not working and how do I fix this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#command">Command</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#volumes">Volumes</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#networkTab">Network</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#labels">Labels</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#environmentTab">Environment Variables</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#security">Security</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content tab-content-border" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="command" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="commands" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Command</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="commands" id="commands" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="entryPoint" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entry Point</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="entryPoint" id="entryPoint" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="workingDir" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Working
                                                Directory</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="workingDir" id="workingDir" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="user" id="user" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Console</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="it" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="it">Interactive & TTY
                                                            <small>(-i -t)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="tty" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="tty">TTY
                                                            <small>(-t)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="interactive" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="interactive">Interactive
                                                            <small>(-i)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="none" class="form-control" type="radio" checked/>
              <label for="none">None</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I increased .form-group{ margin-bottom } and it worked fine.
And are you talking about the "Console" part at the end of the snippet or...? Be more specific please

Comment: And if you are talking about that part ... that is _one single_ form-group element, so adding margin on that won’t do anything in regard to the input fields that are contained in it. Those are individually wrapped in `<div class="radio radio-info">`, so you probably want to specify margin for those ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a class to the form group div. In this case I've added the class "input-box".

```
      <div class="form-group input-box">
        <label for="entryPoint" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entry 
          Point</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="entryPoint" id="entryPoint" class="form-control" 
          type="text"/>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

And for the CSS...

```
.input-box {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

This should add a 30px gap between each input.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippet. I have added a margin-bottom class to each input.

Also when you are adding a div tag with row, make sure you add a container before. It is a must to add otherwise content will overflow.

Hope this solves your question.

```css
.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#command">Command</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#volumes">Volumes</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#networkTab">Network</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#labels">Labels</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#environmentTab">Environment Variables</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#security">Security</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content tab-content-border" style="width: 100%">
      <div id="command" class="tab-pane fade in active">

        <div class="form-group margin-bottom">
          <label for="commands" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Command</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="commands" id="commands" class="form-control margin-bottom" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="entryPoint" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entry Point</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="entryPoint" id="entryPoint" class="form-control margin-bottom" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="workingDir" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Working
                                                Directory</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="workingDir" id="workingDir" class="form-control margin-bottom" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="user" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="user" id="user" class="form-control margin-bottom" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Console</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <div class="radio radio-info">
                <input name="console" id="it" class="form-control margin-bottom" type="radio" />
                <label for="it">Interactive & TTY
                                                            <small>(-i -t)</small>
                                                        </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio radio-info">
                <input name="console" id="tty" class="form-control" type="radio" />
                <label for="tty">TTY
                                                            <small>(-t)</small>
                                                        </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <div class="radio radio-info">
                <input name="console" id="interactive" class="form-control" type="radio" />
                <label for="interactive">Interactive
                                                            <small>(-i)</small>
                                                        </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio radio-info">
                <input name="console" id="none" class="form-control" type="radio" checked/>
                <label for="none">None</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sdasdasd 
Please go through this sample snippet:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Bharadhwaj/ckckkz66/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **row** class just go through this fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/Bharadhwaj/3bfpnu94/1/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#command">Command</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#volumes">Volumes</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#networkTab">Network</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#labels">Labels</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#environmentTab">Environment Variables</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#security">Security</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content tab-content-border" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="command" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="commands" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Command</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="commands" id="commands" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="entryPoint" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entry Point</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="entryPoint" id="entryPoint" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="workingDir" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Working
                                                Directory</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="workingDir" id="workingDir" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="user" id="user" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Console</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="it" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="it">Interactive & TTY
                                                            <small>(-i -t)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="tty" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="tty">TTY
                                                            <small>(-t)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="interactive" class="form-control" type="radio" />
              <label for="interactive">Interactive
                                                            <small>(-i)</small>
                                                        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info">
              <input name="console" id="none" class="form-control" type="radio" checked/>
              <label for="none">None</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```